# SQL and Grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

Lost in SQL on grouping.  I have a table that looks like this:

```
start stop source
1     1    A
2     2    A
3     3    B
4     4    B
5     5    B
```

And I need to group it into something like this:

```
start stop source
1     2    A
3     5    B
```

The minimum number in start with the maximum number in stop for each source.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 7):

You just need to add a `MIN()` and `MAX()` aggregate with a `GROUP BY`:

```
Select   Min(Start) As Start,
         Max(Stop)  As Stop,
         Source
From     YourTable
Group By Source
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select min(start),max(stop),source from test
group by source
```